# Unable to load data from API when changing min SDK to 2.12.0 from 2.7.0. what am I doing wrong? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am making a practice mobile application using flutter, where I load data by calling a third-party API. I want to use late keyword to integrate a feature for which i need to change min SDK version to 2.12.0 from 2.7.0. But after doing that i am unable to load data from API. I am using future builder and ill share it's code before and after changes.

before changing min sdk to 2.12.0:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ApiService client = ApiService(pageIndex);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: client.getArticle(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
        List article = snapshot.data;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                );
              },
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              itemCount: article.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return NewsScreenWidget(
                  author: article[i].author,
                  title: article[i].title.toString(),
                  description: article[i].description.toString(),
                  url: article[i].url.toString(),
                  urlToImage: article[i].urlToImage,
                  publishedAt: DateTime.parse(article[i].publishedAt),
                  content: article[i].content.toString(),
                );
              });
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.black,
            strokeWidth: 5,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

After changing min SDK to 2.12.0

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ApiService client = ApiService(widget.pageIndex);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: client.getArticle(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
        var article = snapshot.data;
        if (article == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          var datalength = article.length;
          if (datalength == 0) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('No data found'),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                );
              },
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              itemCount: datalength,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return NewsScreenWidget(
                  author: article[i].author,
                  title: article[i].title.toString(),
                  description: article[i].description.toString(),
                  url: article[i].url.toString(),
                  urlToImage: article[i].urlToImage,
                  publishedAt: DateTime.parse(article[i].publishedAt),
                  content: article[i].content.toString(),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Currently, I am just seeing CircularProgressIndicator using the above code, but when I switch back to the branch where min SDK is 2.7.0 everything works (but can't use the late keyword).

Any help would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: what do you see if you `print(snapshot)` before `var article = ...`?

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' getting this error just checked

Comment: so your `Future` receives an error, try `print(snapshot.stackTrsce)` to see where it comes from

Comment: I/flutter (13402): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (13402): #10     _FutureBuilderState._subscribe.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
I/flutter (13402): <asynchronous suspension>
This is where is the problem i guess using stacktrc, idk what it means ?

Answer (score 0):

These are best practices when making a future builder:

```
FutureBuilder<YOUR CLASS>(
future: future,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    // do something with logic
    return WIDGET;
  }
  
  if(snapshot.hasError) {
   return Text(snapshot.error);
  }

  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

},
),
```

for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html